# Flex / ActionScript - Click Through An Element To Application Behind Air App

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flash-builder

I'm attempting to build a desktop AIR app using flex/Action Script in Flash Builder.

My desired functionality is this:
- transparent background
- semitransparent (alpha 0.5) item/element that ignores all mouse events and "passes clicks through" to the application behind the app

So essentially what I want to have is that the element handles mouse events in exactly the same way a transparent background does - ie. it is like you're clicking on the application behind

Here is a code example of what I have tried. In the below example clicking on the button fires the "window clicked" alert to demonstrate that the click is being ignored by the button and reaching the window with the transparent background. When I remove the click handler though, clicking on the button does not result in the click being passed through to application behind, like a click anywhere else on the transparent background does.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       alwaysInFront="true"
                       creationComplete="maximize();">
    <fx:Style> 
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"; 
        s|WindowedApplication 
        { 

            skinClass:ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin"); 
            background-color:#999999; 
            background-alpha:"0"; 
        }          
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public function windowClicked():void{
            Alert.show("window clicked");
        }

        </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Window id="mainWindow" height="100%" width="100%" mouseChildren="false" backgroundAlpha="0">

        <s:Button label="Click Through Me Please" alpha="0.5"/>

    </s:Window>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: use the mouseChildren and mouseEnabled properties :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick comment to your question but thought I would elaborate in an answer.

Since I'm sure you are going to do more than your example up there, here is how those properties work:

mouseEnabled="false" - this says you can't click me but you can click my children. This works well when you are disabling a single item or want click event to pass through an item to it's children.

mouseChildren="false" - this says you can't click my children.  This is useful if you are goin to build complex overlays in your app that might contain 10 display objects and want want the mouse to ignore them all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Jason. I'm using mouseChildren at the moment which is letting the window handle any clicks on the button. The problem is though that this click doesn't "pass through" the window to whatever is behind the AIR app. It stops at the window even though it is alpha=0. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yes, that is what I was trying to say.  In your case, you need BOTH mouseChildren and mouseEnabled since although the label inside the window is disabled, the actual window itself is not.  So in you example, the window WILL catch all event that pass through the label.  if you set <s:window mouseEnabled="false" mouseChildren="false" > neither the label or the window will now generate click events. also, how did windowClicked() get called ever?  I do not see any click event listeners registered in your code.  Did you take it out testing?

Comment: Thanks again @jason-reeves - Yes, I removed the click listener for testing. With the change you've suggested the click event no longer gets called but the click still doesn't go through to the application beneath. Maybe this isn't possible? Here is my code: `<s:Window id="mainWindow" height="100%" width="100%" mouseChildren="false" mouseEnabled="false" backgroundAlpha="0" click="windowClicked()">
  <s:Button label="Click Through Me Please" alpha="0.5" mouseEnabled="false"/>
</s:Window>`